# Unable to compare the JSON String Response in the “if” Statement in android using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley, android-webservice

I am getting JSON String Response in a string variable.
I want to compare it in the “if” statement. But program cannot go to the “if” statement.
But it shows the response in the TextView.

Here is my if statement

```
  if (myObjAsString == "WRONG_PASS_ERROR") { //USER_EXISTS_ERROR //WRONG_PASS_ERROR

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
```

Here is my code.

```
String url = "http://someexample.com/signin.php";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            String myObjAsString = jsonResponse.getString("type");

                            if (myObjAsString == "WRONG_PASS_ERROR") { //USER_EXISTS_ERROR //WRONG_PASS_ERROR

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            mTV.setText(myObjAsString);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                // the POST parameters:
                params.put("email", "example@outlook.com");
                params.put("password", "*****");
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
```

Comment: Use `String.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: use `.equals("WRONG_PASS_ERROR")` to compare strings. `==` cannot be used.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK how can i edit this question, that is duplicated with another question.

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad: now you can edit it if u have any other issue but if u have only `compare strings` issues then it is duplicate

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Ok. i have not another issue. But i searched i can't find the question or solution, hence i posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals`. Objects comparison is done like this in java.

`if (myObjAsString.equals("WRONG_PASS_ERROR"))`

or even this will protect from npe:

`if ("WRONG_PASS_ERROR".equals(myObjAsString))`

Answer (score 0):

For comparing strings you do not use the "==" operator, instead you use equals() method. For eg: if(string1.equals(string2))

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
if (myObjAsString.equals("WRONG_PASS_ERROR")) // Change this condition
{ 
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```